# C# winforms. DI Autofac. Синглтон зависимость= Статический объект или все таки внедрение зависимости во все формы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, di

Существует сервис AuthenticationService, который используется всеми формами для проверки прав доступа пользователя к определенным действиям.

Воспользовался советом Pavel Mayorov (спасибо ему огромное) начал внедрять DI в WinForms проект.

Вкратце, DI в WinForms: Если форма хочет управлять временем жизни внедренного сервиса (и всего его scope), то нужно обернуть сервис в IOwner.
Дочерняя форма со всеми зависимостями создается через фабрику Func, сама фабрика внедряется в конструктор родительской формы как и обычный сервис.
Нужно правильно задать время жизни всех зависимостей и все будет ОК).

У меня есть IAuthentificationService который синглтон и зависит от IUserRepository.
IAuthentificationService нужно внедрить во все формы, и возникает желание просто разрезолвить сервис в корне компановке (Program.cs) и обращаться к static полю откуда надо.
При этом преимущество DI по разрешению зависимостей IAuthentificationService и подмене IUserRepository сохраняются.

Можно ли так делать для синглтон зависимостей, которые сложно прокинуть во все формы?
И что в этом плохого?

```
static class Program
{
    public static IAuthentificationService AuthenticationService { get; set; }     //Доступ для Form

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
       AuthenticationService= AutofacConfig.Container.Resolve<IAuthentificationService>();

       //.......

       //Запуск MainForm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С таким подходом у вас будут проблемы в том момент, когда `IAuthentificationService` перестанет быть синглтоном. Например, когда вы захотите написать для вашей программы модульные тесты... Так что лучше все-таки внедрять его как зависимость.

Обычно большое число зависимостей - не страшно, вам же все равно не вручную конструкторы вызывать.

---

Но если вам **очень** не хочется делать зависимость через конструктор - можно использовать внедрение свойства. Вообще-то так делать не рекомендуется, но для классов которые являются точками входа в ваш код иногда приходится делать исключение.

Для этого сначала надо объявить атрибут, которых отделит внедряемые свойства от обычных:

```
/// <summary>
/// Отмечает свойство как обязательное к заполнению после создания объекта.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
sealed class InjectAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Теперь можно добавить свойство к вашей форме:

```
[Inject]
public IAuthentificationService AuthenticationService { get; set; }
```

Осталось настроить Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<YourForm>()
    .PropertiesAutowired((p, obj) => p.GetCustomAttribute<InjectAttribute>() != null);
```

PS Еще раз обращаю внимание, что это решение нельзя использовать для всех классов. Просто потому что *"обязательное к заполнению свойство"* с точки зрения языка - чушь, компилятор за этим не следит и любой объект можно создать и без заполнения его свойств.

Comment: Понял, Модульные тесты для UI пока не писал, но проблему с ними понял. Буду придерживаться подхода внедрения через конструктор.

Comment: Наверно не по теме вопрос, но осталось у меня в голове еще 1 непонятка). Если конструктор формы принимает кроме зависимости еще и результат локальной работы метода. Например ctorForm(ILogger logger, int result){ ... }. В таком случае удобнее конструктор оставить только для зависимости  ctorForm(ILogger logger){ ... }, а result вынести в public свойство и выставлять после создания объекта?

Comment: @Aldmi в таком случае можно использовать фабрику с параметром (`Func<int, SomeForm>`)

Comment: точно, мы же фабрику вручную вызываем, и параметр можем передать), спасибо за участие еще раз.